# Plot trajectories on Google Maps like interface in python

Tags: python, google-maps

I have multiple csv files containing latitudes and longitudes coordinates of trajectories by a single driver. I wish to plot those trajectories on a single google map like image with start and end points marked (Start1, End1 and Start2, End2, etc). The language to be used is python. I have found a few solutions on this site, but all those require signing up for google API or involve html programming. Here is an example:

```
Latitude,Longitude
42.4289382,-83.4918764
42.4289354,-83.4918778
42.4289314,-83.4918781
42.4289279,-83.4918766
42.4289224,-83.4918761
42.4289178,-83.4918743
42.4289122,-83.4918721
42.4289052,-83.4918677
42.4288966,-83.4918583
42.4288875,-83.4918431
42.4288803,-83.4918213
42.4288744,-83.4917965
42.4288724,-83.4917663
42.4288749,-83.4917305
42.4288787,-83.4916908
42.4288822,-83.4916514
42.4288852,-83.4916168
42.4288879,-83.4915859
42.4288911,-83.4915549
42.4288945,-83.4915197
42.4288975,-83.4914802
42.4289024,-83.4914329
42.4289104,-83.4913779
42.4289163,-83.491319
42.4289215,-83.4912562
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try folium: https://github.com/python-visualization/folium

That way you don't need google maps api and html.